# Unauthenticated User Access throws AuthenticationException after Migration to Spring Security 6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

We have migrated to Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security 6. The behavior of users who are not authenticated has changed.

Unauthenticated users should have Anonymous Authetification as before. Instead we get an AuthenticationException.

Is this behavior correct in the new version of Spring Security 6 or do we need to adjust our WebSecurityConfig?

Here is our filter chain:

```
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    log.debug("Configuring HTTP Security");
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors()
        .and()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions().disable()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/sf/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/health").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/metrics").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/error").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/favicon.ico").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/info").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new RolesToRightsConverterFilter(s3RSpringConfig), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(new Slf4jMDCFilter(authService, tracingService), RolesToRightsConverterFilter.class)
        .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(new AadJwtBearerTokenAuthenticationConverter());

    return http.build();
  }
```

Comment: You didn't enable anonymous authentication. I believe that that isn't enabled by default anymore.

Comment: It should be active per default: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/anonymous.html

Comment: it says "Anonymous authentication support is provided automatically when you use the HTTP configuration" in the "Configuration" part.